# nodejs how to test big output text

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, debugging, delta, file-comparison

I have project compile js to js.

I wrote filename.js and compile to filename.out.js, and check manually filename.out.js, next time when I modify my compiler, I hope the output does not changed, if it changed show the diff.

```
function testFile(filename){
  var code = fs.readFileSync(filename + '.js', 'utf-8');
  var expect = fs.readFileSync(filename + '.out.js', 'utf-8');
  assert.equal(pro.compile(code), expect);
}

['groups', 'steps', 'serial', 'parallel'].forEach(testFile);
```

Every time it said AssertionError, but should not be, and it can not give diffrent.

Comment: Do you know that they are identical? Could there be a difference in whitespace? if you dump out some props like: console.log(pro.compile(code).length); and console.log(expect.length); are they the same?

Comment: thank you for log length, save my life. 1 size bigger, strange. trim() then they are same.

Comment: Maybe a white space at the end of the file. Or the file is encoded with BOM.

Answer (score 0):

> thank you for log length, save my life. 1 size bigger, strange. trim() then they are same